# Clearing Empty Strings from an Array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm dealing with a bunch of arrays made of strings and many a times I've written `.delete_if { |str| str.empty? }`

Now, I know I can add this method to the array class myself but I'm hoping there's a built in way to do this without having non-standard methods added to base classes. As much fun as adding methods to base classes is, it's not something I wanna do for maintainability reasons.

Is there a built in method to handle this?

Comment: I have the same problem as you. Almost always, I want to do that right before `join`, so in my case, I made a method similar to `join` but removes blanks previously.

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: @fl00r Whether or not there is a built in way to do it.

Comment: @sawa, there is `compact` method that deletes all nil elements, but there is no standart method to delete all empty strings.

Comment: @fl00r Right. That will be the short answer to the question.

Comment: `compact` doesn't delete elements, it returns a new array not containing the elements. Non-destructive methods are generally easier to use as they do not depend on side effects.

Comment: @Rein Henrichs, okey there is `compact!` method :)

Comment: What's wrong with just adding a new method to the Array class?

Comment: Nothing wrong if it is well documented before usage and if it is clear for all teamworkers :)

Comment: Some great work-arounds, but unfortunately the actual answer is **no.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove blank elements from an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878697/how-do-i-remove-blank-elements-from-an-array)

Answer (score 40):

There is a short form

```
array.delete_if(&:empty?)
```

Comment: If you are using Rails, array.delete_if(&:blank?) is a better option to avoid a NoMethodError if one of the values is nil.

Comment: `array.compact.delete_if(&:empty?)` will handle the nil and the blank in pure Ruby.

Answer (score 8):

You can use this method:

```
    1.9.3p194 :001 > ["", "A", "B", "C", ""].reject(&:empty?)
    => `["A", "B", "C"]`
```

Please note that you can use the `compact` method if you only got to clear an array from nils.

Answer (score 5):

Well, there is **Array.delete**. It returns what's deleted (or nil if nothing is deleted) however, which feels clumsy. But it does deliver and does not fail on non-string elements:

```
ar = ['a', '', 2, 3, '']
p ar.delete('')  #=> ""
p ar             #=> ["a", 2, 3]
```

Comment: I like this one. Some weeks ago on SO was discussion about method that deletes an element and returns itself. like `array.delete(element); array`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this

```
ar = ['a', '', 2, 3, '']
ar = ar.select{|a| a != ""}
```

I hope this will work for you

Answer (score 0):

You can use .select! but you're still going to run into the same problem.

Instead of modifying array, you could create a utility class instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below solution. I hope it ll help you.

array = ["","",nil,nil,2,3]
array.delete_if(&:blank?) => [2,3]

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to remove nil:

```
arr = ['',"",nil,323]
arr.map!{|x|x==''?nil:x}.compact!

=> [323]
```

Map, ternary operator, compact

Comment: Unlike the other methods, this line evaluates as the returned array rather than what has been removed

Answer (score 0):

For **simple** work around:

```
my_array = ['a', '', 2, 3, '']
compact_array = my_array.select(&:present?)
# => ["a", 2, 3]
```

Here:

We select only item of array that ruby think it's present while
`nil` and `""` is not present? in ruby

Comment: `.present?` is a rails method.

Comment: @JohnCoote, Yes, for more detail: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-present-3F

Comment: Another solution:

['a', '', 2, 3, ''] - ['']

Answer (score 0):

As of Rails 5.2, Enumerable now supports `.compact_blank`, which does precisely what you're asking for:

```
[1, "", nil, 2, " ", [], {}, false, true, 3].compact_blank
# =>  [1, 2, true, 3]
```

It works on hashes as well, removing pairs that have a blank *value*.

Docs: https://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/compact_blank