# How do I remove blank elements from an array?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have the following array

```
cities = ["Kathmandu", "Pokhara", "", "Dharan", "Butwal"]
```

I want to remove blank elements from the array and want the following result:

```
cities = ["Kathmandu", "Pokhara", "Dharan", "Butwal"]
```

Is there any method like `compact` that will do it without loops?

Comment: Might be worth updating the accepted answer to @Marian13's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62719314/4055042) now Rails 6 has `compact_blank`.

Answer (score 560, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, one is `reject`

```
noEmptyCities = cities.reject { |c| c.empty? }
```

You can also use `reject!`, which will modify `cities` in place. It will either return `cities` as its return value if it rejected something, or `nil` if no rejections are made. That can be a gotcha if you're not careful (thanks to ninja08 for pointing this out in the comments).

Comment: Or if you prefer more compact `cities.reject!(&:empty?)`

Comment: hm, why not `cities.reject!(&:blank?)`?
`empty?` is for arrays

Comment: @Nico `blank?` is only available through `ActiveSupport`. Standard Ruby does use `String#empty?`: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-empty-3F

Comment: `reject` is better than `reject!` because `[].reject!(&:empty?)` returns `nil`, `[].reject(&:empty?)` returns `[]`

Comment: @aNoble what do you call that feature that you mentioned?

Comment: watch out with reject!. reject! will return nil if no changes are made to the array. If you want to return the array when no changes have been made, just use reject without the bang.

Comment: @ninja08 Honestly, I'm not sure if there is a common name for it. I suppose it's one form of the unary ampersand, so you could call it that. But the unary ampersand is also used for passing blocks around, not just for turning symbols into procs.

Comment: @NickRes But doesn't `reject` without the bang create a shallow local copy? If you need the returned value, you could also do something like `cities.reject!(&:empty?); cities` to use the `!`/bang/in-situ variant.

Comment: And @aNoble (ninja08's comment seems to be deleted): The common name for it seems to be [pretzel colon](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/what-does-the-array-map-ampersand-colon-name-syntax-mean-in-ruby)

Answer (score 185):

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > ["", "A", "B", "C", ""].reject(&:empty?)

=> ["A", "B", "C"]
```

Comment: I would prefer to use .reject(&:blank?) to avoid nil values as well

Comment: @RanGalili `blank?` is a good choice but its a `rails` method, and this question is regarding the plain `ruby`

Answer (score 117):

Here is what works for me:

```
[1, "", 2, "hello", nil].reject(&:blank?)
```

output:

```
[1, 2, "hello"]
```

Comment: @Tom blank? is a Rails specific method.  Doesn't exist on Array for plain ruby.  You will have to use empty? or write your own method.

Comment: Because `NoMethodError: undefined method empty? for nil:NilClass` , `:blank? ` is better than `:empty?`

Answer (score 65):

### compact_blank (Rails 6.1+)

If you are using `Rails` (or a standalone `ActiveSupport`), starting from version `6.1`, there is a [`compact_blank`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-compact_blank) method that removes `blank` values from arrays.

It uses [`Object#blank?`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F) under the hood for determining if an item is blank.

```rb
["Kathmandu", "Pokhara", "", "Dharan", nil, "Butwal"].compact_blank
# => ["Kathmandu", "Pokhara", "Dharan", "Butwal"]

[1, "", nil, 2, " ", [], {}, false, true].compact_blank
# => [1, 2, true]
```

Here is a [link to the docs](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-compact_blank) and a [link to the relative PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/36412).

A destructive variant is also available. See [`Array#compact_blank!`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.1.0/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/enumerable.rb#L256).

---

If you have an older version of `Rails`, check [`compact_blank` internal implementation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.1.0/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/enumerable.rb#L191).

It is not so complex to backport it.

```rb
def compact_blank
  reject(&:blank?)
end
```

---

If you need to remove only `nil` values, consider using Ruby build-in [`Array#compact`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-trunk/Array.html#method-i-compact) and [`Array#compact!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-trunk/Array.html#method-i-compact-21) methods.

```rb
["a", nil, "b", nil, "c", nil].compact
# => ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Answer (score 57):

In my project I use `delete`:

```
cities.delete("")
```

Comment: elegant!  unfortunately doesn't return the remaining array, but pretty slick

Comment: The Array.delete is counter-intuitive. It operates like a .delete!() if such a method existed. The .delete() operates directly on the array in a destructive manner.

Answer (score 46):

When I want to tidy up an array like this I use:

```
["Kathmandu", "Pokhara", "", "Dharan", "Butwal"] - ["", nil]
```

This will remove all blank or nil elements.

Comment: Actually, The Tin Man's answer is better as it will also remove anything which matches Object#blank? i.e. nil, "", "\n", "   ", "\n\r", etc. Unlike the accepted answer, it will also work without Rails.

Answer (score 29):

#### Most Explicit

```
cities.delete_if(&:blank?)
```

This will remove both `nil` values and empty string (`""`) values.

For example:

```
cities = ["Kathmandu", "Pokhara", "", "Dharan", "Butwal", nil]

cities.delete_if(&:blank?)
# => ["Kathmandu", "Pokhara", "Dharan", "Butwal"]
```

Comment: Removing punctuation and adding a colon gives "Cities: delete if blank" :D

Comment: blank is a ruby or rails method?

Comment: @ArnoldRoa It is a Rails method.

Comment: what if there is a space between the empty string?

Comment: @StevenAguilar a space is considered as length 1 (because a space is a character). " ".blank? => false

Answer (score 23):

Try this:

```
puts ["Kathmandu", "Pokhara", "", "Dharan", "Butwal"] - [""]
```

Comment: This is slick, and doesn't return ""! This is a great lil trick.

Comment: ["Kathmandu", "Pokhara", " ", "Dharan", "Butwal"] - [""] - will not work in this case

Comment: 2.0.0-p247 :001 > ["Kathmandu", "Pokhara", "", "Dharan", "Butwal"] - [""]
 => ["Kathmandu", "Pokhara", "Dharan", "Butwal"] 
Seems to work for me.  Why do you think it doesn't work?

Comment: @Raels, the blank string in this case is not empty. It has a single space within it.

Comment: @Chandranshu I beg to differ.  I copied and pasted the text into an editor and found there was no space between the quotes as you suggested.  If there was, then subtracting ["", " "] would work. superluminary's example is similar and works as well.  The original request was to remove "blank elements" not "elements that are blanks", and the example blank element was shown in the OP as "".

Answer (score 20):

Use `reject`:

```
>> cities = ["Kathmandu", "Pokhara", "", "Dharan", "Butwal"].reject{ |e| e.empty? }
=> ["Kathmandu", "Pokhara", "Dharan", "Butwal"]
```

Comment: Or, as aNoble noted above, `reject(&:empty?)`.

Comment: Symbol to proc is slower in 1.8.7 than the block format. It is on par from what i've seen in 1.9.2

Comment: This is good as it will remove any element which matches Object#empty?, eg. "\n", "    ", nil, "\n\n\n", etc...

Comment: What version of Ruby/IRB? It works fine in 1.8.7-p358, 1.9.3-p448 and 2.0.0-p247.

Comment: `nil.empty?` booom break!

Comment: @Naveed, do not change people's code in their answers. You are welcome to improve formatting, spelling and grammar, but their code is theirs. Feel free to suggest improvements in a comment. The problem domain was for blank entries, not nil.

Comment: @AllenMaxwell @Naveed If your array has nil elements, precede the `reject(&:empty?)` with `compact` e.g. `[nil, ''].compact.reject(&:empty?)`

Comment: Better yet, see [Map and Remove nil values in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485468/map-and-remove-nil-values-in-ruby/13485482#13485482). Don't immediately reach for `compact`. Instead search to figure out why they are there and fix that problem because using `compact` often results in wasting CPU cycles doing something that could be avoided.

Comment: `reject(&:empty?)` will work for empty strings, however it's safer to defend against `nil` at the same time with `reject(&:blank?)`, this will catch any `nil` or `""` entries in the array.

Answer (score 14):

```
cities.reject! { |c| c.blank? }
```

The reason you want to use `blank?` over `empty?` is that blank recognizes nil, empty strings, and white space. For example:

```
cities = ["Kathmandu", "Pokhara", " ", nil, "", "Dharan", "Butwal"].reject { |c| c.blank? }
```

would still return:

```
["Kathmandu", "Pokhara", "Dharan", "Butwal"]
```

And calling `empty?` on `" "` will return `false`, which you probably want to be `true`.

Note: `blank?` is only accessible through Rails, Ruby only supports `empty?`.

Answer (score 12):

There are already a lot of answers but here is another approach if you're in the Rails world:

```
 cities = ["Kathmandu", "Pokhara", "", "Dharan", "Butwal"].select &:present?
```

Comment: `present?` comes from `ActiveSupport`. This has a no Rails tag and requiring an extra gem for one method seems excessive.

Comment: @Naveed, you should preface this with "If you're using RoR". I won't downvote it because it's still useful information for beginners.

Answer (score 11):

To remove nil values do:

```
 ['a', nil, 'b'].compact  ## o/p =>  ["a", "b"]
```

To remove empty strings:

```
   ['a', 'b', ''].select{ |a| !a.empty? } ## o/p => ["a", "b"]
```

To remove both nil and empty strings:

```
['a', nil, 'b', ''].select{ |a| a.present? }  ## o/p => ["a", "b"]
```

Comment: `['a', nil, 'b', ''].select(&:present?)` for shorthand

Answer (score 10):

Here is one more approach to achieve this

we can use `presence` with `select`

```
cities = ["Kathmandu", "Pokhara", "", "Dharan", nil, "Butwal"]

cities.select(&:presence)

["Kathmandu", "Pokhara", "Dharan", "Butwal"]
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I had some `"      "` elements in my array that were not removed with the reject method. Your method removed `nil` `""` or `"      "` items.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a solution if you have mixed types in your array:

```
[nil,"some string here","",4,3,2]
```

Solution:

```
[nil,"some string here","",4,3,2].compact.reject{|r| r.empty? if r.class == String}
```

Output:

```
=> ["some string here", 4, 3, 2]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can Try this

```
 cities.reject!(&:empty?)
```

Comment: maybe u meant `cities.reject!(&:blank?) `

Answer (score 2):

```
 cities = ["Kathmandu", "Pokhara", "", "Dharan", "Butwal"].delete_if {|c| c.empty? }
```

Comment: delete and arranging would be a costly operation

Answer (score 2):

Shortest way `cities.select(&:present?)`

Answer (score 1):

**Update in reject and reject!**

> **NOTE:** I came across this question and checked these methods on the *irb console* with `ruby-3.0.1`. I also checked the ruby docs but this is not mentioned there. I am not sure from which ruby version this
> change is there. Any help from the community is much appreciated.

With `ruby-3.0.1` we can use either `reject` or `reject!`

```
cities = ["Kathmandu", "Pokhara", "", "Dharan", "Butwal"]
cities.reject{ |e| e.empty? }
=> ["Kathmandu", "Pokhara", "Dharan", "Butwal"]
```

or shorthand

```
cities.reject(&:empty?)
=> ["Kathmandu", "Pokhara", "Dharan", "Butwal"]
```

both will return `[]` no matter we have an empty value or not?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

another method:

```
> ["a","b","c","","","f","g"].keep_if{|some| some.present?}
=> ["a","b","c","f","g"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Plain Ruby:

```
values = [1,2,3, " ", "", "", nil] - ["", " ", nil]
puts values # [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score -3):

Update with a strict with `join` & `split`

```
cities = ["Kathmandu", "Pokhara", "", "Dharan", "Butwal"]
cities.join(' ').split
```

Result will be:

```
["Kathmandu", "Pokhara", "Dharan", "Butwal"]
```

Note that: this doesn't work with a city with spaces

Comment: Looks very risky!

Comment: This will definitely fail if you have city like "New York" or "Naujoji Akmene" :)