# How do I strip off nil elements from the end of an array if all my elements are nil?

Tags: arrays, ruby, null, trim

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  I want to strip off `nil` elements from the end of an array, so I'm using

```
row_data.pop until row_data.last
```

but if the array only contains `nil` elements, this seems to cause some kind of infinite loop because the call never returns.  How do I account for the fact that the array might contain all nil elements?

Comment: For an empty array, what does row_data.last evaluate to? How can an empty array be detected? Update the logic condition accordingly.

Comment: When you say, "Update the logic condition accordingly", how do I do that?

Comment: `.. until updated_logic_condition_that_will_be_true_when_element_is_falsey_or_array_is_empty` (also, the original condition shown will also exclude `false` values).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add an extra check to see if the array is empty.

```
row_data.pop until row_data.last || row_data.empty?
```

Comment: Very nice. It may read better to write `row_data.pop while row_data.any? && row_data.last.nil?`. Also, this does not return the modified `row_data`, so another line `row_data` is needed if, for example, it's wrapped in a method.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array#rindex](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-rindex) to obtain the right-most non-nil entry (or determine that every element in the array is `nil`).

```
def kill_nils_at_end(arr)
  ndx = arr.rindex(&:itself)
  ndx ? arr[0..ndx] : []
end

kill_nils_at_end [1,nil,1,nil,nil,nil]
  #=> [1, nil, 1]
kill_nils_at_end [nil,nil,nil,nil,nil,nil]
  #=> []
```

This does not mutate the original array. If you wish to modify the array in place, change the penultimate line to

```
arr.replace(ndx ? arr[0..ndx] : [])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Most readable

```
arr = arr.reverse.drop_while(&:nil?).reverse
```

Most efficient

```
arr.slice!(0..arr.rindex { |each| nil != each }.to_i)
```

Answer (score -1):

If all `nil`s are to be removed, try this:

```
[1, nil, 3, nil, nil].compact #= [1,3]
```

see [Map and Remove nil values in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485468/map-and-remove-nil-values-in-ruby)