# Prevent Nil Values in Transformed Array

Tags: arrays, json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, highcharts

Removing `nils` is [quite simple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13485482/1296209), however, I'd like to know:

1) What am I doing wrong, why does my array result below include `nils`?

2) How I can PREVENT the `nils` from being added to my array, instead of removing them after the fact.

```
@cars = Array.new
plucked_array = [
    [8, "Chevy", "Camaro", 20],
    [9, "Ford", "Mustang", 55],
    [9, "Ford", "Fusion", 150]
]
plucked_array.
    each { |id, make, model, model_count|
      @cars[id] ||= {name: make, id: make, data: []}
      @cars[id][:data].push([model, model_count])
    }
puts @cars.inspect
#=>[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, {:name=>"Chevy", :id=>"Chevy", :data=>[["Camaro", 20]]}, {:name=>"Ford", :id=>"Ford", :data=>[["Mustang", 55], ["Fusion", 150]]}]

puts @cars.compact.inspect
#=>[{:name=>"Chevy", :id=>"Chevy", :data=>[["Camaro", 20]]}, {:name=>"Ford", :id=>"Ford", :data=>[["Mustang", 55], ["Fusion", 150]]}]
# This gives the result I'm looking for, 
# just wondering how to best get transformed array without the post-cleanup.
```

I also attempted @theTinMan's [recommendation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13485482/1296209) to `select` first, then `map`, but I had the same results:

```
plucked_array.select { |id, make, model, model_count|
  @cars[id] = {'name' => make, 'id' => make, 'data' => []}
}.map { |id, make, model, model_count|
  @cars[id]['data'].push([model, model_count])
}
puts @cars.inspect
#=>[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, {:name=>"Chevy", :id=>"Chevy", :data=>[["Camaro", 20]]}, {:name=>"Ford", :id=>"Ford", :data=>[["Mustang", 55], ["Fusion", 150]]}]
```

I've tried, with partial success, to use Hash instead of an array for `@cars`. This prevented nils, but my end goal is to build "drilldown: series[]" below, which is an array of hashes:

```js
// Create the chart
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Imaginary Car Stats'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Click the columns to view models.'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Total car count'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.y}'
            }
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.2f}%</b> of total<br/>'
    },
    /*I have separate `pluck` query for this top-level series:*/
    "series": [
        {
            "name": "Cars",
            "colorByPoint": true,
            "data": [
                {
                    "name": "Ford",
                    "y": 205,
                    "drilldown": "Ford"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Chevy",
                    "y": 20,
                    "drilldown": "Chevy"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Other",
                    "y": 16,
                    "drilldown": null
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "drilldown": {
        /*This is the array of hashes I'm attempting to create:*/
        "series": [
            {
                "name": "Ford",
                "id": "Ford",
                "data": [
                    [
                        "Fusion",
                        150
                    ],
                    [
                        "Mustang",
                        55
                    ]
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Chevy",
                "id": "Chevy",
                "data": [
                    [
                        "Camaro",
                        20
                    ]
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/drilldown.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason your code is behaving the way it does is because `array[8] = x` inserts `x` at position 8 in the array, and ruby fills the spaces up to 8 with nils.

```
a = []
a[7] = 4
a == [nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, nil, 4]
```

You need `@cars` to be a hash - not an array

I think this will do what you are trying to do:

```
plucked_array = [
    [8, "Chevy", "Camaro", 20],
    [9, "Ford", "Mustang", 55],
    [9, "Ford", "Fusion", 150]
]

cars = plucked_array.each_with_object({}) do |(id, make, model, count), cars|
  cars[id] ||= {id: id, make: make, data: []}
  cars[id][:data] << [model, count]
end

p cars.values
```

Which actually is almost identical to @Austio's solution.

Comment: Updating `@cars = Array.new` to `@cars = Hash.new` does provide to data without `nils`, however, I do need an `array` in the end.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for more of a reduce approach because you are taking a list and boiling it down into another object.  `each_with_object` does the reduce but implicitly returns the obj (in this case cars) in every loop

```
new_list = plucked_array.each_with_object({}) do |(id, make, model, model_count), cars|
  # return before mutating cars hash if the car info is invalid
  cars[id] ||= {name: make, id: make, data: []}
  cars[id][:data].push([model, model_count])
end

# Then in your controller to handle the usage as an array
@cars = new_list.values
```

Side note: map is normally more for transforms or equivalent changes, which is i think why it feels off here.

Comment: Well, this is each_with_object, very different than each.  Each is just a loop iterator, each_with_object reduces the list.  i don't understand what you mean because if you use the reduce approach, just don't push to the array when you run into something you don't want.

Comment: ok, i'm 100% that this is a correct way to do it so please post if you run into anything and i'll help if i can

Comment: Sorry, I'm a ruby noob. This outputs a hash, but in the end I'm needing it in a sorted array instead. Should I just use `<%=@cars.values%>` in the view or is there a better option?

Comment: Hey no problem at all, that is what i would do.  The hash makes it convenient for mapping properly with lookup by id and then it being in array format is a view concern, so either set @cars = cars.values in the controller or just access the way you are doing.

Comment: Updated with the casting

Comment: Would there be any benefits to using `each_with_object` over my solution with `each` if `@cars` was originally set to a new hash instead of an array? In a quick benchmark, it appears that using `each_with_object` is appx. 30% slower than my original solution with `@cars = Hash.new` replacing `@cars = Array.new`...this might be micro optimzation at this point, but it will be used for reporting, which will have a much larger `plucked_array` in a real-world situation

Comment: It is a micro optimization for sure, the biggest benefit of using each_with_object is that it is clear what the inputs and outputs are.  Using each to mutation an external object makes it harder to understand imo.  In any real world situation you will run into limitations with displaying in the browser or with speed of network request way before switching this would help.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest grouping by id, then creating a `hash`:

```
plucked_array.group_by(&:first).transform_values{ |v| v.map{ |id, make, model, model_count|  {name: make, id: make, data: [model, model_count]} }}

#  {8=>[{:name=>"Chevy", :id=>"Chevy", :data=>["Camaro ls", 20]}], 
#   9=>[{:name=>"Ford", :id=>"Ford", :data=>["Mustang", 55]}, {:name=>"Ford", :id=>"Ford", :data=>["Fusion", 150]}]}
#  }
```

---

**Edit - update do match the edit of the original question (get series of data for Highcharts)**

This should return the required result:

```
plucked_array.map.with_object(Hash.new([])) { |(id, make, model, model_count), h|
  h[make] += [[model, model_count]] }.map { |k, v| {name: k, id: k, data: v }}

#=> [{:name=>"Chevy", :id=>"Chevy", :data=>[["Camaro", 20]]}, {:name=>"Ford", :id=>"Ford", :data=>[["Mustang", 55], ["Fusion", 150]]}]
```

The first part builds an hash like this.

```
#=> {"Chevy"=>[["Camaro", 20]], "Ford"=>[["Mustang", 55], ["Fusion", 150]]}
```

Passing `Hash.new([])` as object allows to insert elements to the default array.

Finally the hash is mapped to the required keys.

Comment: From a quick benchmark, this appears to be the most efficient option provided so far. However, I do need an array in the end.

Comment: @webaholik, made an edit after having seen the updated question. Maybe this give the required result.