# Remove nil and blank string in an array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am new to Ruby and stuck with this issue. Let's say I have an array like this:

```
arr = [1, 2, 's', nil, '', 'd']
```

and I want to remove nil and blank string from it, i.e. final array should be:

```
arr = [1, 2, 's', 'd']
```

I tried `compact` but it gives this:

```
arr.compact!
arr #=> [1, 2, 's', '', 'd'] doesn't remove empty string.
```

I was wondering if there's a smart way of doing this in Ruby.

Comment: I checked it, it doesn't have nil, how would you remove nil and empty string at the same time. How's it duplicate?

Comment: blank? returns true for both nil and '' (as well as other things like '/n'). [Docs link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F)

Comment: Yes, `blank?` works but is not available in plain Ruby. It comes with Rails.

Comment: Abraham, that's in Rails not in Ruby.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll remove the duplicate.

Comment: Why downvote? people should atleast give an explanation of a downvote, is this how community help new people here?

Comment: `compact` returns new array, but leave the first array as it is (with `nil` inside). `compact!` changes existing array and returns it (if there will be no `nil` it returns nil). 
http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-compact

Comment: @RedZagogulin I read it, the only issue was to remove blank strings and I didn't know about the other operations mentioned in the answers. My question was clear I think, have no idea why people go downvote for no reason without explaining anything.

Comment: @anInteger I don't understand the downvotes either. It's not a duplicate (which IMO is never a reason to downvote anyway), the question is clearly stated and it's clear that you tried to find your own solution.

Comment: @Зелёный blank won't work in Ruby, I hope you know that. :)

Comment: I've fixed this injustice for you. And yes, I agree that it would be nice if people will explain their downvotes.

Comment: @Зелёный I will, give beginners some time to breath.

Comment: Why was this question marked as a duplicate? It's clearly not a duplicate of the question referenced.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You could do this:

```
arr.reject { |e| e.to_s.empty? } #=> [1, 2, "s", "d"]
```

Note `nil.to_s => ''`.

Comment: For those who see this answer first: as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/41810889/2441263, it's simpler to use `arr.reject(&:blank?)`

Comment: Ah! Thanks Cary, my mistake! I was moving too fast and didn't see that comment on the linked answer. Still hope my comment helps rushed folks like me who got here by googling the best way to do this in rails. Maybe not the place for this question, but why the preference for referencing a handle (that can change) over linking directly to the answer?

Comment: `:blank?`will only work in Rails as it is an ActiveSupport method and not a part of ruby.

Answer (score 27):

Since you want to remove both `nil` and empty strings, it's not a duplicate of [How do I remove blank elements from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5878697/473467)

**You want to use `.reject`:**

```
arr = [1, 2, 's', nil, '', 'd']
arr.reject { |item| item.nil? || item == '' }
```

**NOTE:** `reject` with and without bang behaves the same way as `compact` with and without bang: `reject!` and `compact!` modify the array itself while `reject` and `compact` return a copy of the array and leave the original intact.

If you're using Rails, you can also use `blank?`. It was specifically designed to work on `nil`, so the method call becomes:

```
arr.reject { |item| item.blank? }
```

Comment: Integer does not respond to `empty?`

Comment: Oh. You're absolutely right. Thanks for pointing this out. I updated the answer.

Comment: can't upvote because of the low reputation but this is also a nice answer. Also, thank you for the tip but I am not using Rails for now. :)

Comment: This is the answer I upvote. The way I like to use it is as `arr.reject &:blank?`.

Comment: For older versions of ruby you can use `empty?` instead of `blank?`

Comment: `arr.reject {|e| e.to_s == ''}` is probably easier than `e.nil? || e == ''`

Answer (score 27):

I tend to do:

```
arr = [1, 2, 's', nil, '', 'd']
arr.reject(&:blank?)
```

returns:

```
=> [1, 2, "s", "d"]
```

Comment: It wouldn't work as blank? doesn't work on integer or nil class.

Answer (score 14):

### compact_blank (Rails 6.1+)

If you are using `Rails` (or a standalone `ActiveSupport`), starting from version `6.1`, there is a [`compact_blank`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-compact_blank) method which removes `blank` values from arrays.

It uses [`Object#blank?`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F) under the hood for determining if an item is blank.

```rb
[1, 2, 's', nil, '', 'd'].compact_blank
# => [1, 2, 's', 'd']

[1, "", nil, 2, " ", [], {}, false, true].compact_blank
# => [1, 2, true]
```

Here is a [link to the docs](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-compact_blank) and a [link to the relative PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/36412).

A destructive variant is also available. See [`Array#compact_blank!`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/enumerable.rb#L255).

Comment: Good find! Gives us another good reason to upgrade to Rails 6.1.

Answer (score 8):

`arr.reject(&:blank?)`

Just use this, no need to anything else.

Comment: `blank` isn't a Ruby method, it's a Rails one, so you should add the active_support needed library, and the question has tagged Ruby not Rails. Anyways, this answer states something pointed before.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `-` to remove all `nil` and `''` elements:

```
arr -= [nil, '']
#=> [1, 2, "s", "d"]
```

[**Demonstration**](http://repl.it/xfp)

Or `compact` and `reject` with shortcut (*in case you are not using Rails where you can just use `arr.reject(&:blank?)` )*:

```
arr = arr.compact.reject(&''.method(:==))
#=> [1, 2, "s", "d"]
```

[**Demonstration**](http://repl.it/xfp/5)

Answer (score 2):

You can use compact with reject

```
arr = [1, 2, 's', nil, '', 'd']
arr = [1, 2, 's', 'd']

arr = arr.compact.reject { |h| h == "" }
```

or

```
arr = arr.compact.delete_if { |h| h == "" }
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest  and fast way of doing this is :

```
arr = [1, 2, 's', nil, '', 'd'] - [nil,'']
```

```
==> arr = [1, 2, 's', 'd']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use compact and delete_if method to remove nil and blank string in an array in Ruby

```html
arr = [1, 2, 's', nil, '', 'd']
arr.compact!.delete_if{|arrVal| arrVal.class == String and arrVal.empty?}
=> [1, 2, "s", "d"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: I am considering the array might have string with white spaces in it.

You can do:

```
arr = [1, 2, 's', nil, ' ', 'd']
arr.reject{|a| a.nil? || (a.to_s.gsub(' ', '') == '') }
#=> [1, 2, "s", "d"]
```

or:

```
arr.reject{|a| a.nil? || (a.to_s.gsub(' ', '').empty?) }
#=> [1, 2, "s", "d"]
```

or if you want to update `arr` object itself then:

```
arr.reject!{|a| a.nil? || (a.to_s.gsub(' ', '') == '') } # notice the ! mark, it'll update the object itself.
p arr #=> [1, 2, "s", "d"]
```

Comment: good use case, I'll keep this mind if I come across such situation in future. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

```
[1, 2, "s", nil, "", "d"].compact.select{|i| !i.to_s.empty?}
```

Comment: You might consider using `reject`, rather than `select`, bot to get rid of `!` and because `compact` is also a form of rejection.  To me, "reject this and reject that" reads better than "reject this and select that".

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work for your case :

```
arr = [1, 2, 's', nil, '', 'd']
arr.select{|x| x.to_s!="" }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably add `.strip` to eliminate potential whitespace headaches (assuming its not a rails app).

```
array = [1, 2, "s", nil, "     ", "d", "\n"]
array.reject!{|a| a.nil? || (a.to_s.strip.empty?) }

#=> [1, 2, "s", "d"]
```